# app:processReleaseResources issue during release

Tags: react-native

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:C:\internship amnil tech\QFX\android\app\src\main\res\layout\launch_screen.xml:5: AAPT: error: resource drawable/launch_screen (aka com.qfx:drawable/launch_screen) not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

how to solve  this error during release via android studio

i want to solve this issue